# Video interfering with :hover

Tags: html, css

I've made a drop-down menu in the header of my website using `:hover`. The menu works fine, as long as there is no video underneath.

The menu closes when moving the pointer over the drop-down menu if (and only if) there is a video underneath. To my understanding, the video is interfering with the hover function.

It shouldn't have anything to do with the `z-index`, since the menu is shown on top of the video, unless also hovering over it.

HTML for the video:

```
<video controls>
    <source src="../video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

HTML for drop-down:

```
<li class="login">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <ul>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 2</li>
            <li>item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

CSS for drop-down:

```
.dropdown {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 1;
}

.login:hover .dropdown { display: block; }
```

Comment: Can we get a link to the actual project so we can try the code our ourselves?